# Why does Vegeta tolerate Android 18?

Tags: dragon-ball-z

Probably a stupid question but...

I was watching Resurrection 'F' and when 18 appeared on screen this question popped into my head. During the Android saga he was pretty much curb stomped by 18 right? (Memories are a little clouded) And Vegeta being as prideful as he is would he really let 18 live regardless of how "good" he became?

Is it just a plot point that wasn't explored?
Is Vegeta's switch to the good side cause for this? I just find this one a little hard to believe. I'd probably believe it more that since 18 is important to Krillin and he is important to Goku, that Goku had something to do with it.

Again, sorry if this question is dumb.

Comment: Havning not seen the series in a while i do remember that Krilan explained to Goku during the Buu Saga(?) that 18 was a human to begin with and after the Android Saga all her "Android" components were removed (which is how the 2 of them had a daughter). maybe to Vegeta since 18 was an Android when she kicked his ass but she isn't now probably means he's ok with her.

Comment: Its not the only time vegeta got stomped into the ground and was friendly with the doers later on.......goku and gohan there during their first meeting with him. ALTHOUGH the three are of the same species so that could play a role there in vegetas eyes.

Comment: Well, by the time the Androids and Cell arc happen, Vegeta already has a baby son with Bulma.

Perhaps he started playing nice not to lose the life he already had on Earth.

Comment: Not sure if this counts as a legitimate answer, so I'll put it here. Vegeta isn't evil anymore. In the Buu saga, they used a dragon ball wish to bring back all the good people that were killed. Vegeta was one of the people brought back to life, indicating that he isn't actually a bad person anymore. Another example of someone he could have killed but didn't was Piccolo.

Comment: @Memor-X AFAIK 18 never stopped to be an android. She was able to give birth because she is human based. The wish Krillin asked for was to remove 17 and 18 bomb, but they still keep their powers, as seen in the next Saga's tournament.

Comment: @krikara We are talking about the Android Saga. Vegeta resurrection happens at the end of the Buu saga, after fighting and nearly banishing for ever for protecting the Universe. A bit earlier in the saga, Vegeta is given the destiny of evil people on the Other World, even if he sacrificed his own life, meaning Vegeta full redemption doesn't happen until Ultimate Buu battle.

Comment: more important stuff than that happened, and Vegita probably doesn't care about it that much anymore.

Secondly, Vegita is now much more powerful than 18, so 18 isn't a viable rival anymore, so he doubly doesn't care.

Answer (score 6):

The primary reason that Vegeta tolerates Android 18 is that he has changed.

- He has become more human than a savage who destroyed planets for fun. This change of his is evident and there are many more instances of this in DBS (Dragon Ball Super). For example, in episode 2, he took a day out of his training schedule and went to the amusement park with Bulma and Trunks and the incidents that occur over there also highlight this sea change in his personality.
- In fact, he's in touch with his human emotions, an instance being when
  he gets angry over Beerus slapping Bulma when she slaps him for
  ruining her birthday party and makes up his mind to fight him whereas
  till that point he had been swallowing up his pride and acting like a
  clown (episode 7).
- It can also be said that he now accepts things as they are. He
  realized that he isn't the strongest out there, and has shifted his
  focus to becoming the best. He also has realized that there is nothing going to be achieved by revenge, so he doesn't seek revenge anymore.

This explains why Vegeta tolerated Android 18.

Answer (score 3):

During the Android Saga, after the defeat, Vegeta trains in the Room of Spirit and Time (aka Hyperbolic Time Chamber) and becomes so powerful he could probably beat 18 in seconds. After fighting much more powerful enemy (which also humilated him), I think Vegeta no longer feels as he has something to demonstrate crushing 18. Everybody knows he is far, far superior.

That isn't the only time Vegete renounce revenge. He could arguably want to take revenge on the fighters that defeated him in the battle that surely hurted more his pride, Yajirobe, Gohan and Krillin, specially when the last two of them outsmarted him in Namek. But he prefer to focus on his rivality with Goku.

Also, note that at the end of the Android Saga, Goku was dead, so it wasn't him who stopped Vegeta. On the other hand, Gohan was alive and more powerful that his father.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because Vegeta only aim is to get stronger than Goku, Beerus, and Whis and prove himself at this point in the series. He just ignores all the others since they are weakling to him now and a waste of time also the fact that goku would stop him from hurting any of his friends including 18 who is married to krillin. Vegeta knows he can spend his time better by training with Whis than trying to start a fight with 18. Beerus would also stomp vegeta and vegeta needs to still get stronger than beerus. He has alot to work on so really I think he doesnt care about 18 and just focuses on other stuff he does care about. He spend a year IIRC training with whis while goku was on earth farming and doing chi chi work. Vegeta let majin buu go as well after he sacrificed himself to kill him. So really it has been a turning point for Vegeta

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because Vegeta's last statement after Cell Games:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GJ64JXN_3mI

At that point Vegeta pretty much lost his pride and a will to fight, so he just couldn't pull himself together to go after 18.

Sure, he got better after some time, but since his battle against 18 so much time has passed and so much stuff happened, he either no longer cared or even remembered about executing his revenge.

Also, let's not forget, that if he actually tried to do something against her, Krillin would just call Gohan and Bulma. I don't think Vegeta would dare to go against the two of them at any moment between Cell Games and Buu Saga.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, Vegeta has 2 goals -

a. defeat kakarot.

b. bring back Saiyan planet

1. Vegeta was always a good guy from the heart but what changed him so much was freeza. I will consider freeza was the person who makes him heartless. he was helpless and weak against freeza. Vegeta loves Saiyan and Saiyan planet and he wants Saiyan race to keep on living so one day he can rebuild the new Saiyan planet. (so he is a good guy he loves his own planet and race ). he knows only Saiyan can defeat Frieza, and freeza destroyed his planet because of that reason only.
2. Vegeta is arrogant but not bad. As you know Saiyan loves to fight so as Vegeta.
3. Vegeta considers himself a high-rank Saiyan "Saiyan price, he wants to lead all the saiyan but as he knows goku is stronger than him, he can't become a leader until he defeats kakarot.
4. Vegeta considers earth as his new home and loves earth as much as he loves saiyan planet. ( so he is a good guy )
5. He was once a bad guy but still accepted by everyone and that changed him, so it is ok someone like android 18 to get another chance. even boo is dangerous but boo also got another chance.